# compressing CSS sprite code with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, sprite, css-sprites

I created a sprite which has at least 50 small images in it.

Currently I'm making each element accessible with this stylesheet:

```
#L A{background-image:url('http://example.com/spritefile');text-align:right;width:95px;height:63px;background-color:#220;color:#FFF;float:left;margin:2% 1%;display:block}
#L0{background:0 0}
#L1{background:-96px 0}
#L2{background:-192px 0}
.....
#L50{background:-960px -128px}
```

and this HTML:

```
<div ID="L">
<a ID="L0" href="1">1</a>
<a ID="L0" href="2">2</a>
<a ID="L0" href="3">3</a>
....
<a ID="L50" href="50">50</a>
</div>
```

With my code and spritesheet created, users can select whatever element they want from a grid that adjusts to almost any screen width.

Now what I want to do is condense the code so that I don't have so many declarations for background position, but at the same time, make the site work for all (including those who have javascript turned off).

I can easily roll off a loop in javascript for each of the individual positions, but is there a way to globally define the background image in javascript like I can in CSS?

For example,

Instead of using:

```
<script>
for (n=1;n<50;n++){
 document.getElementById('L'+n).backgroundPosition=x+"px "+y+"px";
 document.getElementById('L'+n).backgroundImage='url("http://example.com/spritefile")';
 x=x+20;if ((n % 10)==0){x=0;y=y+20;}
}
</script>
```

Could I somehow call backgroundImage only once and make it apply to all anchor elements within the sprite sheet div?

Something like this but something that actually works:

```
<script>
 document.allchildrenof.getElementById('L').backgroundImage='url("http://example.com/spritefile")';

for (n=1;n<50;n++){
 document.getElementById('L'+n).backgroundPosition=x+"px "+y+"px";
 x=x+20;if ((n % 10)==0){x=0;y=y+20;}
}
</script>
```

I apologize if my javascript is a bit rusty.

Comment: I also tried `document.getElementById('L').children.style.backgroundImage='url:("sprite.jpg")';` and got an error.

Answer (score 0):

So, there's two different ways you can do this.

If the CSS will remain static (and you're just trying to collapse the CSS to be easier to modify), use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). If you need the background to change sometimes dynamically while the user is interacting with your page, use Javascript.

**SASS**

To implement SASS, it's fairly simple.

```
@for i from 1 through 50{
    #L#{$i}{
        // your styles here
        // you can use $i in calculations to dynamically generate numbers
        // For example
        background: $i * -96 0;
    }
}
```

**Javascript**

For this, it's basically what you already wrote, except instead of writing `element.backgroundImage`, you have to create all the inline styles you want on the element you're creating, and then set the `style` attribute of the new document element, like `element.style="background-image: url('');color: red";`.

Comment: I'm gonna exclude SASS because I'm looking for a solution which doesn't require 3rd party tools. But if I apply the background-image property to each individual element, wouldn't that mean the image has to be fetched x times where x is the number of elements? I'm trying to fetch the image file only once.

Comment: the image will be loaded one time then reloaded from the client's cache without sending further requests to the server

Comment: Exactly what @paolo said; if it's the same image URL, the cache will handle it. Keep in mind that if your image is fetched via some sort of HTTP get variable, such as `mysite.com/static_assets.php?id=1234` then it will not be cached.